# itertools - all integer points between 2 points

Tags: python, tuples

I'm writing a chess game in python. When a king is checked, i need to filter out the possible moves, to block the check, or to move the king. I want to write a function that will return the possible blocking moves, to block the check. A function will look like this:

```
def getBlockingCheckMoves(pieceField,kingPos)
```

For a rook, a long solution would look like this:

> 1. See if x coordinates are same, return tuples made from a range of y's, with the correct increment.
> 2. if y coordinates are the same, return tuples made from a range of x's.

Is there a more pythonic way to accomplish this using itertools?

EDIT: my long version

```
if pieceField[0] == kingPos[0]:
    if pieceField[1] < kingPos[1]:
        return [(pieceField[0],x) for x in range(pieceField[1],kingPos[1])]
    else:
        return [(pieceField[0],x) for x in range(pieceField[1],kingPos[1],-1)]
if pieceField[1] == kingPos[1]:
    if pieceField[0] < kingPos[0]:
        return [(x,pieceField[1]) for x in range(pieceField[0],kingPos[0])]
    else:
        return [(x,pieceField[1]) for x in range(pieceField[0],kingPos[0],-1)]
```

Comment: @downvoter any particular reason to downvote?

Comment: There is no code. What have you written so far? Only function definition?

Comment: My -1 is because you're asking for a more elegant (itertools) solution to a problem that you're describing in two sentences (not even pseudo code) and not code...

Comment: sorry, should have made my question clearer

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski The edit is an improvement so I'm happy to retract my d/v